# apache http and https on single IP

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https

We have apache 2.4 web server running in our environment with Name Based Virtual Hosting.
There is single IP (say X) assigned to this server which is NAT to single private (say Y).

Currently, my ports 80 and 443 listens as below:
0.0.0.0:80 and
0 0.0.0.0:443.
There are many websites running on port 80 [http] [domain1.com, domain2.com etc]
And only single website running on port 443 [https] [say abc.com]

But when mistakenly someone type https://domain.com it shown SSL warning and displays content of abc.com.

As SSL does not work with Name Based virtual hosting this seems normal. But how can I restrict the user from not viewing the page of abc.com when they mistakenly types https on the non-HTTP site hosted in my environment?

Comment: To be clear, you are okay with them getting the SSL warning, right? You just want them not to get the page if they accept the warning. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes david,  I just want them not to get the page if they accept the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Make the very first VirtualHost on port 443 serve a static index.html with explanation, or serve nothing (then it returns standard 404 error, which is also OK).

VirtualHost is first when it appears textually first in a httpd.conf or on the alphabetic order of files in conf.d directory.

The old browsers which don't support SNI will end up here.

Browsers which specify server name other than abc.com will also end up here. User will still see the certificate warning, as the certificate you will provide does not match host name. So it's an ugly workaround.

The second VirtualHost on port 443 should serve abc.com.

Browsers which support SNI (all modern browsers) will end up here.

Comment: thank you for the above explanation. We have done the changes as described above. Presenting the default website if not abc.com.